# Search for Pairs of Values in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my Table i have two IDs
id1 and id2

there might be duplicats like:

```
1 / 1
1 / 2
2 / 1
2 / 2
2 / 2
```

Now i want to search for defined tuples in database like: I want all data for tuples (1,1) and (2,1) and (1,2)

If I have only one id there was the nice way of searching with something like:

```
WHERE id1 IN (1,2,3)
```

If I copy it for both fields, that would be:

```
id1 in (1,2)
id2 in (1,2)
```

But this would obviously also select (2,2) which ist not wanted.

Is it possible to do something like this with the tupels? (Backup solution is a loop with one query per tupel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In don't mysql here right now to test, but I believe the following should work

```
select *
  from yourTable
 where concat(cast(id1 as char), '/', cast(id2 as char)) in ('1/1', '1/2', '3/1');
```

In this case, you want to search for tuples 1/1 or 1/2 or 3/1

or if `id1` and `id2` are constrained between [0, 9], then you can also

```
select *
  from yourTable
 where id1*10 + id2 in (11, 12, 31);
```

Comment: both ids might be up to 4 or 5 characters long. I guess this would not work then? (how could it know if 111 is 11/1 or 1/11?)

Comment: Combining values with an expression feels like a solution that a query optimizer would be unable to optimize.  *I doubt this will scale well, on any DB engine.* AFAIK, the only way it could find matches would be an "n-squared" approach - string-concatenate all possible pairs. So its essential to test performance on a table filled with sample data, that is as large as the final production table is anticipated to grow to. (While that is a truism in general, I am saying that it is especially important for this answer.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I couldn’t agree more. That was actually the reason I provided the second solution

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
pair_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id, pair_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO test (pair_id) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (3);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE (id, pair_id) IN ((1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2));
```

That's how I'd construct the table and the query in case of tuples you described. Tested it at MySQL 5.1, it works, it returns first 3 records.

Comment: does it need to be the combined primary key to work? Mine is only on id and it is not possible to change that.

Comment: It doesn't have to be PK, but I didn't test what happens if it isn't. PK's are perfect when there are clashes - they cannot occur so I used a PK.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to work out what was going on here, so for future readers:  The `INSERT INTO test ..` creates 12 records, with ids 1-12.  The first 3 records are `(id: 1, pair_id: 1), (id: 2, pair_id: 1), (id:3, pair_id: 1)`. These records match the `SELECT ..` condition. The only records with `pair_id: 2` have ids 5-8; none of those match the final requested tuple `(id: 4, pair_id: 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

and a not clause:

```
where id1 in (1,2)
and id2 in (1,2)
and not (id1 = 2 and id2 = 2)
```

Comment: if im looking for more tupels, then i would have to list huge amounts of tupels not to select. this would not simplyfy at all